# how to show statistics of active online users in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

Hello friends i am trying to show status of online users and the pages each user is now watching i have created a table in database which contains information for users that are logged on and save the current status,but i don't think it is an elegant method for saving users session i also want to save user's information that aren't logged in (Guests users)via IP Address.
The page which shows user information is a private page that only site administrator can look at it.

`Are there any SQL SERVER feature or C# namespaces?`

`What am i suppose to do with this?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to count active user you can check this [Online active users counter in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29792/Online-active-users-counter-in-ASP-NET)

In order to count active users on SQL SERVER check this [SQL active user count](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/12b021e4-9474-4300-825d-2a382fc1064a)

and for SQL SERVER user statistics check this [Reports –User Statistics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2008/02/26/sql-server-management-studio-standard-reports-user-statistics-databasename.aspx)

and in point of saving visited pages of a user it depends on the number of users that daily visit your website and the art of your design. using database could be a good method but i don't think there is a general method to achieve sort of things

Comment: it seems you provide me good links for counting active users,but i need an article that discuses how experts go over this issues and more common in programmers community thanks.